# Why is my package of cheese blown up like a balloon

Tags: cheese

This is a package of balderson old cheese,the package has ballooned up. Is it safe to eat? The expiry date is Nov.2021

Comment: Did you mean to include a picture? I don't see one.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  You seem to have intended to add a picture to this question, but there isn't one.  Try to edit your question and add the photo?

Comment: I agree with Joe's answer, but worth noting that if you have a sealed container at high altitude it may balloon up simply due to the lower air pressure compared to where it was packaged. If you live at high altitude I'd assume you'd be familiar with the phenomenon though.

Answer (score 4):

It’s most likely not safe to eat.

Something biological has occurred (like fermentation), creating a gas that has inflated the package.

There are food products that are meant to have this happen, but if it’s not, then you should not eat it.   And maybe see about getting a refund if it was purchased recently.